# Remove Last and begin specific character from String

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I want to remove a specific character from the end and the beginning of string.

Example:

- Input ==> **Maro;** Output should be **Maro**
- Input ==> **Maro** Output should be **Maro**
- Input ==> **Maro;Mike;** output should be **Maro;Mike**
- Input ==> **;Maro;Mike** output should be **Maro;Mike**
- Input ==> **;Maro;Mike;Tim;** output should be **Maro;Mike;Tim**

Any idea

Comment: Have you tried with `Trim` method of string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
input.Trim(";".ToCharArray())
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string s = ";Maro;Mike;Tim;";
string s2 = s.Trim(';');
```